# Robot Framework -connect to MS SQL databse - Login error

Tags: sql-server-2008, robotframework

I am trying to connect to MS SQL server through robot framework on remote machine

I have installed the required libraries and db api

the keyword is as follows

> Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymssql    database='MSSQL', user='user', password='password', host='192.168.**.***'

I am getting following error

> OperationalError: (18456, "Login failed for user 'user'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (192.168.86.130:1433)\n")

I even tried the same with pyodbc db api . but facing the error for the same

Comment: Are you certain that your database is configured for a user named `user` with a password `password`? Did you check the database server error logs like it suggests?

Comment: yes the username and password are correct I have tried to login manually in database and it works

Comment: This part "Adaptive Server connection" suggests to me that it's using the Sybase driver. Could there be a mixup of the driver in the ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect connection string. Try this one:

`DRIVER=\{SQL Server\};SERVER=${host};DATABASE=${db_name};UID=${username};PWD=${password}`

Comment: I tried it as follows -                                                                                       Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymssql     database=\{'MSSQL'\}, user=${user}, password=${pwd}, host=${ip}                                                          this gives following error - FAIL : AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @SnehalGokhale What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2017

Comment: @SnehalGokhale Did you try pyodbc? Because I am using pyodbc and connection string from my reply and it works without problem with SQL Serve 2016.

Comment: Can you please print the total command alongwith the db string